# Converting simple jQuery animation to zepto.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

I'm trying to convert my current project from jQuery to zepto and I'm having trouble with even basic things such as:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    // Animate loader off screen
        $("#loading-overlay").delay(2000).fadeOut(1000, function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

As far as I got. Do I still just use $(window).load?

```
$('#loading-overlay').animate({
}, 2000, 'ease-out')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last version of Zepto expelled the fx/animations from the core. Are you sure you have included the fx plugin?